# Shoutcast streaming

Tags: java, android, streaming, shoutcast

I'm currently working on a app for a podcast (katg.com) which will let you listen live etc... however, I have not found any open source code available to stream shoutcast. I know there are some ways of doing it, but I find it hard to find any available code on the net that explains it for a java/android beginner like myself.
 Anyone know of any libs/tutorial/examples/code that shows how to do this on android?

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Erich seems to have accidentally posted the wrong link, here's another resource about the protocol: http://forums.radiotoolbox.com/viewtopic.php?t=74

The shoutcast stream itself is accessible via HTTP. For example via Telnet:

```
$ telnet myshoutcastserver.com 8000
GET / HTTP 1.1

..............a lot of streaming stuff........
```

So you could try to buffer the stream data and when there is enough to play pass it to a MediaPlayer instance.

Comment: I tried doing that. But the mediaplayer is playing faster than what the stream is downloading, so it gets to a part and it repeats from the begining. Keeps doing that :( ANY SOLUTION? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a shoutcast streaming application for android on github:
http://github.com/Dawnthorn/nagare/

I didn't try it and it seems to be not continued. However maybe the code helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some text on how the Shoutcast protocol works: [SHOUTcast Protocol](http://forums.radiotoolbox.com/viewtopic.php?t=74).  It's not as good as sample code, but it might come in useful.

**Edit**: Fixed the link.

Comment: Your link goes to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found it by now, Icecast is an open source audio streaming server that supports the SHOUTcast protocol: http://www.icecast.org/index.php