# shoutcast client on android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a shoutcast client on android, but simply parsing a .pls and supplying the stream link to the android mediaplayer does not work. Can anyone suggest a way I can go about this? 
Do I have to implement something like a proxy server and buffer the stream data manually?
Thanks
Vamsi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963105/listen-to-a-shoutcast-with-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen to a shoutcast with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963105/listen-to-a-shoutcast-with-android)