# Android Shoutcast: Want help to play ShoutCast Streaming in 1.6

Tags: android, streaming, shoutcast

My application plays ShoutCast Streaming and the target OS is 1.6 and above. I have applied some code from NPR application with some modification.

Here is the code

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
// Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Preparing: " + playUrl);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.start();`
```

The code doesnot play anything on simulator or device(Testing in Samsung Galaxy with 2.1).

---

Here is the LogCat message.

> About to play http://88.191.81.31:8206
>   12-08 14:16:42.229: WARN/MediaPlayer(5520): info/warning (1, 26)
>   12-08 14:16:42.239: ERROR/PlayerDriver(1870): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
>   12-08 14:16:42.239: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5520): error (1, -1)
>   12-08 14:16:42.239: WARN/PlayerDriver(1870): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
>   12-08 14:16:42.259: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5520): start called in state 0
>   12-08 14:16:42.259: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5520): error (-38, 0)
>   12-08 14:16:42.299: INFO/MediaPlayer(5520): Info (1,26)
>   12-08 14:16:42.299: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5520): Error (1,-1)
>   12-08 14:16:42.304: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5520): Error (-38,0)

---

Here is the question. 1. Can you tell me whats happening in device? 2. How to solve this error?.

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `start()` too soon. Javadocs of [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) explain it (look at the picture):

1. Either you have to call `prepare()` before you call `start()`, or
2. You call `prepareAsync()` and wait for `OnPreparedListener.onPrepared()` to be called, then (possibly inside this method) call `start()`.

**Updated:**

Shoutcast streams are nativelly supported only on 2.2. For earlier versions you must create local proxy that changes the response protocol from ICY (shoutcast) to HTTP, which the 
mediaplayer will support. Take a look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java

This has previously been discussed:

[Listen to a shoutcast with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963105/listen-to-a-shoutcast-with-android)

Comment: I have tried this. Its not working Here is the Updated Code `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

   mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
   mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

   mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
     Log.i("In", "Prepared Listener");

     mediaPlayer.start();
    }
   });`     The LogCat Message is in next Comment.

Comment: WARN/MediaPlayer(6592): info/warning (1, 26)
12-08 15:18:18.214: INFO/MediaPlayer(6592): Info (1,26)
12-08 15:18:18.219: ERROR/PlayerDriver(1870): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
12-08 15:18:18.219: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6592): error (1, -1)
12-08 15:18:18.219: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6592): Error (1,-1)
12-08 15:18:18.219: WARN/PlayerDriver(1870): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete

Comment: First: `prepareAsync()` needs to be called after `setOnPreparedListener(..)`. Second: your error is thrown during `setDataSource()`, right?

Comment: I believe you problem lies in the fact that 1.6 does not natively support Shoutcast. I updated the answer.