# Audio Icecast Android Streaming(listening) in ogg/vorbis format

Tags: android, audio-streaming, icecast

I need to make an app which can connect to an Icecast server to listen to a mountpoint in ogg/vorbis format. I have searched alot and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963105/listen-to-a-shoutcast-with-android).

But it doesnot give any way for Icecast streaming.

Please share your ideas/sample code regarding how to to this.

Thanks

EDIT: How to play live streaming in ogg/vorbis format in android ?

Thanks Again...

Comment: Icecast/SHOUTcast are equivalent for playback.

Comment: Hi Brad... I want to make the App that can listen live stream in ogg/vorbis format and it seems that android donot support ogg format for live streaming purpose as it can only play ogg format locally. Please help by sharing any ideas about how to do it..?

Comment: You're right that the built-in player doesn't play OggVorbis over HTTP, but you should still be able to play it in your own application if the codec is available.  I apologize, I am not an Android developer, so I cannot give you specific information, but the posts that you linked to should be able to get you started.  You can treat Icecast like any other HTTP server.