# Webradio on android - Sound glitches via mobile network

Tags: java, android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

I'm trying to make a small app that allows me to stream online radio stations with the android MediaPlayer class. I've read the information about the shoutcast protocol as mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963105/listen-to-a-shoutcast-with-android/) and spend hours trying to fix this issue myself.

As a normal HttpURLConnection or URLConnection doesn't work anymore under Android 4.2.2 I came up with the idea of keeping it simple and using plain sockets to get the work done.
The weird problem I'm facing though, is that when I'm connected to my WiFi it works perfectly fine (as long as I request and handle the metadata information) but if I'm connected to any sort of mobile network such as LTE/4G there's a lot of glitches and I can't get the metadata information anymore as the method returns an unreadable String.

Here's my Code for the streamer:

```
public class Streamer {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Streamer";

    /** The line feed character. */
    private static final char LF = 10;

    /** The carriage return character. */
    private static final char CR = 13;

    private static final CharSequence ICY_META = "icy-metaint:";

    private static final String ICY_METADATA = "Icy-MetaData: 1";

    /** The pattern to match ICY metadata in a stream, e.g. StreamTitle, StreamUrl. */
    private static Pattern ICY_METADATA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("StreamTitle='(.*)';");

    private final StreamEventHandler notifier;
    private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> mQueue;
    private URL mUrl;

    private int mKBytesPerSecond;
    private boolean icy;

    private static final String ICY_BITRATE = "icy-br:";

    public Streamer(StreamEventHandler notifier, BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue) {

        this.notifier = notifier;
        this.mQueue = queue;

    }

    public void stream(URL url) throws IOException {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Streaming from: " + url);
        mUrl = url;
        BufferedWriter outToRadio = null;
        InputStream inFromRadio = null;
        Socket radio = null;
        int metaInt = 0;
        try {

            try {
                radio = new Socket(url.getHost(), 80);
                outToRadio = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(radio.getOutputStream()));
                inFromRadio = radio.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e1.getMessage());
                notifier.onConnectionLost(url);
            }

            String header = "GET " + url.getFile() + " HTTP/1.1" + CR + LF + "Host: "
                    + url.getHost() + CR + LF + ICY_METADATA + CR + LF + CR + LF;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, header);
            try {
                outToRadio.write(header);
                outToRadio.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                notifier.onConnectionLost(url);
            }
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFromRadio));
            String headerLine = null;
            try {
                headerLine = bufReader.readLine();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, headerLine);
                if (!headerLine.contains("200 OK")) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "HTTP error. Didn't receive 200 OK");
                    radio.close();
                    return;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                notifier.onConnectionLost(url);
            }
            while (true) {
                try {
                    headerLine = bufReader.readLine();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, headerLine);
                    if (headerLine.contains(ICY_META)) {
                        metaInt = Integer.parseInt(headerLine.substring(ICY_META.length()).trim());
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Icy Metaint = " + metaInt);
                        icy = true;
                    }
                    if (headerLine.contains(ICY_BITRATE)) {
                        int bitrate = Integer.parseInt(headerLine.substring(ICY_BITRATE.length())
                                .trim());
                        mKBytesPerSecond = bitrate * 1024 / 8;
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Icy Bitrate = " + bitrate);
                    }
                    if (headerLine.equalsIgnoreCase("") || headerLine == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                    notifier.onConnectionLost(url);
                }
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "HTTP request finished. Start streaming!");
            playMp3Stream(inFromRadio, metaInt);

        }

        finally {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Disconnect");
            if (radio != null) {
                radio.close();
            }

        }
    }

    private void playMp3Stream(InputStream in, int metaint) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (icy) {
                playIcyStream(in, metaint);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "found mp3 stream , streaming");
                playUnknownAudioStream(in);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private void playUnknownAudioStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[mKBytesPerSecond];
        int read;
        try {
            while ((read = readFully(in, buf)) != -1 && !notifier.isCancelled()) {
                notifier.bytesBuffered(read);
                synchronized (StreamManagerService.bufGuard) {
                    mQueue.put(buf);
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            reconnect();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private void playIcyStream(InputStream in, int metaint) throws IOException {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Playing ICY stream with metaint: " + metaint);
        byte[] buf = new byte[metaint];
        ByteBuffer bytebuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[mKBytesPerSecond]);
        int read;
        try {
            while ((read = readFully(in, buf)) != -1 && !notifier.isCancelled()) {
                // String rawStream = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
                // Log.d("STREAM", rawStream);
                skipIcyMetadata(in);

                if (bytebuffer.remaining() > metaint) {
                    bytebuffer.put(buf);
                }

                else if (bytebuffer.remaining() == metaint) {
                    bytebuffer.put(buf);
                    putToAudioBuffer(bytebuffer);
                }

                else {
                    int splitPosition = bytebuffer.remaining();
                    bytebuffer.put(buf, 0, splitPosition);
                    putToAudioBuffer(bytebuffer);

                    int offset = splitPosition;
                    splitPosition = offset + mKBytesPerSecond >= metaint ? metaint - offset
                            : mKBytesPerSecond;

                    while (metaint - offset > bytebuffer.remaining()) {

                        bytebuffer.put(buf, offset, splitPosition);
                        putToAudioBuffer(bytebuffer);

                        offset += splitPosition;
                        splitPosition = offset + mKBytesPerSecond >= metaint ? metaint - offset
                                : mKBytesPerSecond;
                    }
                    bytebuffer.put(buf, offset, (metaint - offset));
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "reconnecting...");
            reconnect();
        } catch (SocketException ex2) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "reconnecting...");
            reconnect();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "writing to queue was interrupted");
        }
    }

    private void putToAudioBuffer(ByteBuffer bytebuffer) throws InterruptedException {
        bytebuffer.rewind();
        byte[] oneSecond = new byte[mKBytesPerSecond];
        bytebuffer.get(oneSecond);
        bytebuffer.rewind();

        synchronized (StreamManagerService.bufGuard) {
            mQueue.put(oneSecond);
        }
        notifier.bytesBuffered(mQueue.size());
    }

    private void skipIcyMetadata(InputStream in) throws IOException {

        int val = in.read();
        if (val == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " - First metadata byte: " + val);

        int len = val * 16;
        if (len > 0) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[len];
            int read = readFully(in, buf);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, " - Metadata bytes: " + read);
            String metadataRaw = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, " - Metadata : " + metadataRaw);
            // String metadata = parseIcyMetadata(metadataRaw);
            // notifier.metadataReceived(metadata);
        }
    }

    private int readFully(InputStream in, byte[] b) throws IOException {

        int len = b.length;
        int n = 0;
        while (n < len) {
            int count = in.read(b, n, len - n);
            if (count < 0) {
                if (n == 0) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return n;
                }
            }
            n += count;
        }
        // String metadataRaw = new String(b, "UTF-8");
        //
        // Log.d(LOG_TAG, " - Stream : " + metadataRaw);
        return n;
    }

    public void reconnect() {
        int tries = 1;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) StreamManagerService.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        while (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null || !cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "No internet connection. Reconnection try # " + tries);
            tries++;
            if (tries > 120) {
                this.notifier.onConnectionLost(mUrl);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Internet reconnect established");
        try {
            stream(mUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failed to reestablish connection to stream");
            this.notifier.onConnectionLost(mUrl);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is consumer with the MediaPlayer

```
public class StreamConsumer {

    private static final int INIT_MP_FEED_SIZE = 4;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "StreamConsumer";

    private final IsCancelledNotifier mNotifier;
    private ServerSocket mServerSocket;
    private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> mQueue;
    private MediaplayerRunnable mpRunnable;
    private volatile boolean mNoError;

    public StreamConsumer(IsCancelledNotifier notifier, BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue) {
        mNotifier = notifier;
        mQueue = queue;
        mNoError = true;

        try {
            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0, 0, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0,
                    1 }));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "can't open ServerSocket");

        }

    }

    public boolean streamDataToSocket() {

        BufferedOutputStream outOnClient = null;
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            if (mServerSocket == null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "serversocket = null");
            }
            int currentPort = mServerSocket.getLocalPort();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Port: " + currentPort + " was assigned");

            mpRunnable = new MediaplayerRunnable(currentPort);
            new Thread(mpRunnable).start();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Server is waiting for client on Port: " + currentPort);
            client = mServerSocket.accept();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "client is ready");

            outOnClient = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            boolean initialMPFeed = true;
            while (!mNotifier.isCancelled() && mNoError) {

                if (initialMPFeed) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < INIT_MP_FEED_SIZE; i++) {
                        synchronized (StreamManagerService.bufGuard) {
                            byte[] temp = mQueue.remove();
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Writing " + temp.length + " bytes");
                            outOnClient.write(temp);
                        }
                        // outOnClient.flush();
                        initialMPFeed = false;
                    }
                }

                if (mQueue.size() >= 1) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "in Buffer: " + mQueue.size() + " sec");
                    synchronized (StreamManagerService.bufGuard) {
                        byte[] temp = mQueue.take();
                        outOnClient.write(temp);
                    }
                    // outOnClient.flush();
                }

                Thread.sleep(500);
                if (mNotifier.isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            mpRunnable.releaseMp();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "serversocket couldn't be created, break up Consumer");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mpRunnable.releaseMp();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IO: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "interrupted");
            mpRunnable.releaseMp();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mediaplayer released");
        } finally {
            if (outOnClient != null) {
                try {
                    outOnClient.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "cannt close outputstream");
                }
            }
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "cannt close client socket");
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "end of the Consumer...");
        mpRunnable.releaseMp();
        return mNoError;
    }

    class MediaplayerRunnable implements Runnable {
        private volatile MediaPlayer mp;
        private final int mCurrentPort;

        public MediaplayerRunnable(int port) {
            this.mCurrentPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mediaplayer is starting...");
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {

                mp.setDataSource("http://127.0.0.1:" + mCurrentPort);

                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                        int maxVolume = 100;
                        int currVolume = 25;
                        float log1 = (float) (Math.log(maxVolume - currVolume) / Math
                                .log(maxVolume));
                        mp.setVolume(0, 1 - log1);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mediaplayer started.");
                    }
                });

                mp.prepareAsync();

                mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                        mNoError = false;
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Mediplayer error: " + what + "with extra" + extra);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "cannot set Datasource or Mediaplayer had onPrepare error");
            }

        }

        public void releaseMp() {
            mp.release();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mediaplayer released");
        }
    }
```

If I set the icy-metadata header to 0, I also get the glitches and bleeps. If I set the data source of the MediaPlayer to the streaming URL though, it doesn't have any problems streaming it. Strangely if I send the HTTP header that I get back from the station to the player via my socket, it'll cause a Socket Exception failing the send(either EPIPE: broken pipe, or ECONNRESET)

I'm really confused, because I didn't think there'd be a difference between mobile network and WiFi. Or am I doing something else wrong? Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me to the right solution please?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're having trouble handling the buffers.  I'm not a Java guy, and you've posted a mountain of code in your question, but what you describe is very common if you don't handle a sizeable buffer before doing the decoding of the audio stream.

Comment: I've solved the problem by requesting the data via a http 1.0 request rather than 1.1. I haven't looked into the detailed differences between the two protocol versions yet but I reckon it has something to do with the way of transmitting chunked data. So now if I don't request the icy metadata as I don't really need it, I don't have any glitches anymore. Thanks anyways

Comment: You could also try a request header with `Transfer-Encoding: none` to disable the chunking.  For what it's worth, VLC has this problem and has left it unfixed for years, so it's good that your player has resolved it!